# Does it make sense to use a population parameter like $\sigma$ (population standard deviation) in the formula for SE?

Tags: standard-error, population

Correct me if I am wrong but in the formula for SE

$\text{SE} = \sigma/\sqrt{n}$, the numerator refers to population parameter.

But in practical life, we resort to sampling because we don't know much about the entire population. So shouldn't an error formula involve only sample statistics and not population parameters?

How will I calculate SE, when I do not know what the population sigma is?

Answer (score 2):

What you missed is the difference between the defintion of a parameter and how to *estimate* it from a data sample. What you have given is the definition (in a certain context, such as estimation of means) of standard error. To apply that in practice, you will have to *estimate* it from your data, for instance by replacing the theoretical standard deviation $\sigma$ by some estimate of it, like $S$.

Comment: But isnt the Z score based on population sigma? I am a bit confused here. Let us say I use sample standard deviation. Then my SE is just another estimate which has its own error. When SE itself is defined to estimate the error between sample mean and population mean, if it is further going to be having its own error then that makes it difficult . Need a better explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately most resources online do not clearly explain these differences and it ends up confusing the reader. We need to intuitively know what we are estimating when we use sample SD in the  SE formula and what are we estimating when we use the population SD etc. how is this all tied up to the published Z score tables? Let us say my SE using sample SD is 2. what does this actually mean? If my SE using population SD is 2.5 say, what does this mean? Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have drawn a sample from a population of unknown distribution and you want to say something about the population mean $\mu$ based on the sample mean $\bar{x}$ (this is how I understand your question). To do that, you need some knowledge about how the sample mean relates to $\mu$.

If you start from zero knowledge about the distribution of the population, but have an iid sample, the best you can do is the Central Limit Theorem, which states that as your sample size grows, $n \rightarrow \infty$, the distribution of the sample mean will approach a Gaussian distribution with a certain variance. From zero knowledge to a known distribution is a pretty amazing result! For a thorough introduction, I recommend Casella & Berger's *Statistical Inference*.

The variance of the mean (SE), as you state, is dependent on the population variance $\sigma$, which in most practical cases is unknown and, as already stated, you need to replace $\sigma$ with an estimate, and you end up with adding uncertainty. The nature of that uncertainty is dependent on $\sigma$ through the distribution of the sample variance, and you are back at square one.

There are no simple explanations apart from the definitions themselves and the proofs. Proofs can be quite hard to understand without mathematical training, some of them even with years of university level mathematical studies. But again, I recommend the Casella & Berger book.

Most scientific communities are using the Central Limit Theorem, replacing $\sigma$ with the sample variance, to draw conclusions regarding $\mu$ based on $\bar{x}$ when the population distribution is unknown, ignoring that extra uncertainty.

Comment: "Most scientific communities use CLT replacing σ with the sample variance, to draw conclusions regarding μ based on x¯ when the population distribution is unknown, ignoring that extra uncertainty." I dont get this. If I can just replace population mean with sample mean as a good enough guess because my sample size is large, then why do I even need a concept like standard error? Ideally speaking, the SE is supposed to help us get closer to the population mean. So it should have been defined using sample statistics only and not any population parameters.

Comment: using population parameter in SE, makes the standard error itself erroneous or imprecise since we do not know the population variance. It defeats the whole point of inferential statistics

Comment: You cannot "just replace population mean with sample mean as a good enough guess" and no one is claiming that you can.

Comment: and so? still my original questions remains unanswered. when you have just one sample of n observations drawn from a population, how can the standard deviation of that sample be used in place of the original value which is σ(population)/sqrt(n)? The SE should not ideally have any population parameters as part of its formula, since we do not know anything about the population